# Disable Submit button until 2 or 3 checkboxes are checked, using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to disable Submit button until 2 or 3 checkboxes are checked, using Angular.

See example of start code below. Im not sure if Angular is the best way!

I need support for IE8 and older browsers

Any tip?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var model = {
        user: "Adam",
        items: [{ action: "Flowers", done: false },
        { action: "Shoes", done: false },
        { action: "Tickets", done: false },
        { action: "Cimputer", done: false }]
    };
    var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);
    todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.todo = model;
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
        <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in todo.items">
                    <td>{{item.action}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
                </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the items by done and check if the filtered list length is long enough

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="(todo.items | filter: item.done != true).length < 2" /></td>
```

If you want to restrict the maximum as well you can do the following

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="((todo.items | filter: item.done != true).length < 2) || ((todo.items | filter: item.done != true).length > 3)" /></td>
```

Comment: Works Great!

An improvement if I want mininum 2 and max 3 checked checkboxes, how do I make that?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to support IE8 or older browsers, you can make use of the AngularJS `ngDisabled` directive.

`ngDisabled` allows you to disable a button based on the Boolean value of a `$scope` variable. The following is an example of a button which is disabled when `$scope.isDisabled` is true.

```
<button ng-disabled="{{scope.isDisabled}}">Save</button>
```

You could then use something like `$scope.$watchCollection` to update `$scope.isDisabled` whenever the checkboxes are checked/unchecked.

You can find out more about ngDisabled from the AngularJS docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: I need support for IE8 and older browsers

Comment: @user3635120 - Okay that's fine but then it might have been worth specifying that in the question. I don't appreciate a down vote when my answer answered the question as you had originally written it. By all means don't accept it, and ask for an alternative solution though.